# Read region of a Large Width X Height Image

Tags: image, python-2.7, image-processing, tiff, vips

I have a 1gb image, I want to open this image into 90,000 and 70,000(width X height) at level 0. I even tried with python openslide but didn't work for me.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: what is level 0? what is the pixel format? assuming just a simple grayscale byte image you would end up with almost 6GB of memory. I don't see why you would want to work on a 90,000x70,000 image. explain more

Comment: I have some machine learning project in which am training my neural net , with a different-2 level image so a level is nothing but just a zoom level in a image. Here's the code also  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992165/python-openslide-readregion-not-able-to-get-an-image-at-large-sizewidthxheight

Comment: how many bits per pixel?
and why do you open 2 questions on the same problem?

Comment: vips can process images like this, but you need to say what you want to actually do. You can't feed something that big directly to a neural net, so I guess you want to process in 1k x 1k chunks, something like that? More details please.

Comment: This is the code it's was working on level 6 small width and height but as i increase the width and height not working Help.

result = img_file.read_region((0, 0), 0, (94000, 74000))